# Finding the solutions of $x^y=y^x$ such that $x,y>e$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, exponential-function

I need to show that the set of solutions to the equation $x^y=y^x$ with $x,y>e$, consists precisely of points of the form $(a,a)$ with $a>e$. While this feels intuitively correct ($x,y$ can't both be large without being equal) and using a graphing calculator seems to confirm it, I'm having trouble showing it formally. How should I proceed?

Comment: $$\dfrac{\log x}x=\dfrac{\log y}y.$$

Comment: Hint: the equation is equivalent to $$\frac{x}{\log x} = \frac{y}{\log y} \, .$$Try showing that the function $f(z)=\dfrac{z}{\log z}$ is one-to-one for $z\geq e$.

Comment: @Joe your approach seems the easiest. $f'(z)=\frac{\log z-1}{(\log z)^2}>0$ for $z>e$, therefore $f(z)$ is injective and $x=y$, correct?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Has the easiest job to show that the function is decreasing by taking the derivative

Comment: @V.Ch.: Yes, since $f'(z)>0$ for $z>e$, the function $f$ is one-to-one. By definition, a function $\phi$ is one-to-one on the interval $[a,\infty)$ if $\phi(x)=\phi(y) \implies x = y$ for all $x,y\geq a$. Since $f$ is one-to-one on $[e,\infty)$, the equation $\frac{\log x}{x}=\frac{\log y}{y}$ (equivalent to $x^y=y^x$) only has the solutions $x=y$ on this interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: the equation $x^y=y^x$ is equivalent to $$\frac{x}{\log x} = \frac{y}{\log y} \, .$$Try showing that the function $f(z)=\dfrac{z}{\log z}$ is one-to-one for $z\geq e$.

Comment: The derivative is strictly positive for $z>e$, therefore $f(z)$ is injective and $x=y$. Thanks!

Comment: @V.Ch.: I'm very glad I could help.